# Omitting HashMap name during gson serialization

Tags: java, hashmap, gson

I am looking to serialize my class using gson but I would like to omit the hashmap name. Is this possible with gson?

I have tried writing my own TypeAdapter but the map name is still written as the parent object.

I have a class which looks like

```
public class myClass {
    @Expose
    public Long timestamp;
    @Expose
    public String id;
    @Expose
    public HashMap<String, someOtherClass> myMap = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
                .create();

        return gson.toJson(this);
    }
}
```

current output :

```
{
  "timestamp": 1517245340000,
  "id": "01",
  "myMap": {
    "mapKey1": {
      "otherClassId": "100", // works as expected
    }
    "mapKey2": {
      "otherClassId": "101", // works as expected
    }
  }
}
```

What I am hoping to get :

```
{
  "timestamp": 1517245340000,
  "id": "01",
  "mapKey1": {
      "otherClassId": "100", // works as expected
  },
  "mapKey2": {
      "otherClassId": "100", // works as expected
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your own [`TypeAdapter`](http://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html). See javadoc for example.

Specify it with [`@JsonAdapter`](http://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/annotations/JsonAdapter.html) annotation, or register it with [`GsonBuilder`](http://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html).

```
@JsonAdapter(MyClassAdapter.class)
public class MyClass {
    public Long timestamp;
    public String id;
    public HashMap<String, SomeOtherClass> myMap = new HashMap<>();
}
```

```
public class MyClassAdapter extends TypeAdapter<MyClass> {
    @Override public void write(JsonWriter out, MyClass myClass) throws IOException {
        // implement the write method
    }
    @Override public MyClass read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        // implement the read method
        return ...;
    }
}
```